# How to group by year from a concatenated column

Tags: mysql, sql, date, distinct

Having a MySQL table as this, where the id is a concatenation of the date with **Ymd** format (of the moment the row is inserted) with an incremental id.

```
|     id      |   weight  |
| 20200128001 |    100    |
| 20200601002 |    250    |
| 20201208003 |    300    |
| 20210128001 |    150    |
| 20210601002 |    200    |
| 20211208003 |    350    |
```

To make a sum of 'weight' by a single year I'm making:

```
SELECT sum(weight) as weight FROM `table` WHERE id LIKE '2020%';
```

resulting in this case as:

```
650
```

How can I make it result in a table of weights by year, instead of querying by every single possible year, resulting in this case as:

```
| date |  weight  |
| 2020 |    650   |
| 2021 |    700   |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of the string processing functions in MySQL like `left()`

```
SELECT LEFT(id,4) as Year, SUM(weight) as Weight
FROM `table`
GROUP BY LEFT(id,4)
ORDER BY LEFT(id,4)
```

And if you want to limit the results to just those 2 years

```
SELECT LEFT(id,4) as Year, SUM(weight) as Weight
FROM `table`
WHERE LEFT(id,4) IN (2021, 2022)
GROUP BY LEFT(id,4)
ORDER BY LEFT(id,4)
```